# ResourceDictionary Style Triggers not working

Tags: c#, wpf

from the following Trigger only the Foreground Setter is working. I do not understand why.

```
 <Style   TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
  </Trigger>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What control are you setting this trigger on? Please provide a more complete sample...

Comment: Button Sry did not mentioned it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because the default Button template uses a [ButtonChrome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.buttonchrome.aspx) that draws the border and background and handles states like mouseover and disabled depending on the Windows theme (e.g. Windows XP style, Windows 7 style).

In order to allow your triggers to be applied, you will need to define a custom Button template that uses standard stylable WPF elements, like Border, instead of ButtonChrome.  Here's a bare-bones working example:

```
<Button Content="button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Property=Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Property=BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Property=BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Turns out I have two different button styles. In one of them there is a textblock for linebreaking. How do I consider this in the style(I want to Change the foreground)?

Comment: @Anubis1233 The button's Foreground should be passed down to the TextBlock automatically unless you have another Foreground set somewhere.

Comment: The code is <button><textBlock>hello world!<TextBlock></button> (simpified button code) but it is not passed down

Comment: @Anubis1233 You must have your own TextBlock style (in App.xaml resources for example) with a Foreground setting. If so I would remove that setter and just set foregrounds on containers instead. Does it work if you use `<TextBlock Style="{x:Null}">`? This will force the default style, which should allow it to use the container's foreground.

Comment: @Anubis1233 I will need to see your code then. I can't duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Button in WPF has a default control template.  The correct way to override the Button's default behavior is by overriding default control template. This can be done with something similar to below:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Click Me!">
  <Button.Template>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="bdr_main" CornerRadius="20" Margin="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightGray">
                 <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
           </Border>
           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                     <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                 </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
               </Trigger>
           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Found @ http://harishasanblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/ismouseover-trigger-not-working-in-wpf.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the trigger on the controltemplate.

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="TestButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```